# Is it okay to design a purely managerial class (not meant to be instantiated,) and use all static methods?

Tags: php, class, static

Inside a container object, I have created a class `Factory`, that is responsible for assembling 2 different types of arrays: one that contains multiple `foo` objects, and the other that contains multiple `bar` objects.

I was planning to call them like:

`$this->foos = Factory::assemble_foos()`.

`$this->bars = Factory::assemble_bars()`.

The `Factory` would also theoretically be called to update/delete explicitly declared objects/attributes, as such:

eg. `Factory::destroy_bar( $bar_id )`

eg. `Factory::update_foo( $foo_id, $attr, $val )`

But I'm fairly new to OOP and PHP, and am curious about my approach--I realized that the `Factory` class is purely managerial, and that it's never meant to be instantiated (or at least never instantiated more than once.)

Is there something 'bad practice' about this approach of having a class that's exclusively static methods, and maybe some static attributes? Should I be re-working my code so that my container object instantiates a `Factory`, and make my methods instance methods?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you simply use an internal function in your class i.e., `$this->foos = $this->_assemble_foos()`?

Comment: @ssice - That would require an `assemble_foos()` method in my container object--which I suppose is just as effective... I was just separating the functionality a bit more. That would simplify passing the database to the "assemble" methods.

Comment: If you take a look to the MVC approach, then you'll realize that your `Factory` makes the *Model* part. It does not need to be static, though; you can init a DB connection in the Factory constructor and use an internal object to exec the queries

Comment: @ssice - But for example, I have a `user` class inside the container as well... which also needs database access. Barring a singleton pattern, how would I pass the database TO the `Factory`, `User` and any other classes that need db access?

Comment: In the `Factory`/`User`/... constructors, make a call to `$this->_db = Db::getInstance()`, or make a constructor parametrized with your DB connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a common practice in PHP, it allows you to faux namespace functions.

One thing you may want to do is make `__construct()` private so it can't ever be instantiated.

Comment: Yet another +1 for private constructors.  That trick is as close as PHP gets to static classes.